# How to call an api to initialize a bean inside a scheduled method?

Tags: spring-boot

I have to use a rest api call to get an accesstoken which is valid for 15 minutes. Using that auth token i call other apis. I want to write a scheduler to invoke that api every 15 mins and set it to my bean so that i can autowire my bean and use token in api calls. I could not invoke a @bean annotated method from @sheduled method. Is there any work around?

I could not invoke a @bean annotated method from @sheduled method. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to implement the [observer pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer), wherein one class manages some state (e.g. an API Token) while one or more classes need to be notified when that state changes.

This is possible and can be achieved pretty simply by making your scheduled class a Publisher, and the classes which use the API Token the Subscribers.

```java
// define your Publisher signature
public interface Publisher {
    void subscribe(Subscriber subscriber);
}

// define your Subscriber signature
public interface Subscriber {
    void update(String apiKey);
}
```

Since your `@Scheduled` class needs to push updates, it will be your Publisher.

```java
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Component
public class ApiTokenPublisher implements Publisher {

    private String apiToken;
    private List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Periodically generate a new token, then it
     * updates all the subscribers.
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *") // every minute
    void getApiToken() {
        this.apiToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // or whatever ...
        this.subscribers.forEach(s -> s.update(this.apiToken));
    }

    /**
     * Allow clients (e.g. other classes) to register
     * with this Publisher to be notified about 
     * updates. 
     */
    @Override
    public void subscribe(Subscriber subscriber) {
        this.subscribers.add(subscriber);
    }
}
```

Then you can define your client code (or whichever Bean you want to keep track of the apiToken) as a `Subscriber`, as follows:

```java
import com.example.scheduled.ApiTokenPublisher;
import com.example.scheduled.Subscriber;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UpstreamServerClient implements Subscriber {

    private String apiToken;

    /**
     * At startup, this Spring Component will register itself
     * as a listener to the ApiTokenPublisher Publisher
     */
    public UpstreamServerClient(ApiTokenPublisher apiTokenPublisher) {
        apiTokenPublisher.subscribe(this);
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called by the ApiTokenPublisher Publisher
     * whenever a new API Token has been generated.
     */
    @Override
    public void update(String apiToken) {
        this.apiToken = apiToken;
    }

    void someApiCallWithApiToken() {
        // use this.apiToken to make API calls
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you going. This pattern has multiple variations, so your solution may not look quite like this one. Def. read up on this pattern a bit!

Cheers!

Side-note: looks like scheduled annotations run at the end of their time range. You may want to decorate the token fetching scheduled method with `@PostConstruct` so your first 15 minutes post startup have a valid token as well.